# Show content of referenced field in a block

Tags: drupal, nodes

I have 2 content types in Drupal: Articles and Newspapers. The Article type has a a reference field which points to the Newspapers. Each Article can only reference one Newspaper.
So an article called Sunday reports belongs ta a newspaper The Times, article Monday reports belongs to The New Yorker. I created a view and inside that view a block. So when a user visit that article page it should display in a block to which newspaper it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Views...

1. Add a "contextual filter" of "content:nid".
2. on this filter, set "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE" to "Provide default value",
3. Set "Type" to "Content ID from URL",
4. Then add a "Relationship" to your entity reference field
5. Then in the output fields, add NID and set it to use the relationship.

I am not sure what version of drupal you are using, but it should be basically the same for D7 - D9

Comment: You saved me! I always got to the relationship part but never thought i have to add fields. Thank you